# ANDROID: How to iterate data in firebase when adding a new data?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project that involves adding data to Firebase and every time I add a new data I want to see the result of iterating the child.

[Like for example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veYI5.png)

I have 10 data under wordbank and I want the new added data to be inserted at the end of the list. How do you solve this? Please help! Thank you very much!

Comment: avoid using the structure with numbers as keys, instead use the mAuth getCurrent user or push() method to generate random keys for each node, it will be more easy to get data in the future when your app grows

Comment: thanks for the advice however we have already set other methods to read the file via predefined id.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please responde with @.